# Proposed tag synonym filtering -> filter

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

**Please don't vote on the tag right away.** *It is already at +2, at +4 the synonym gets approved and the tags get mixed, we won't be able to undo that action. So let's discuss here before an irreversible decision is made.*

There is a tag synonym proposed that would [make "filtering" a synonym of "filter"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/filter/synonyms). On the surface this makes sense, but these two tags have different descriptions and are used for different purposes.

Because of the confusing names, these two tags have not always been applied in the right way. But [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter) has mostly been used for filtering rows in a table or database, for filtering inputs, etc. And [filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filtering) has mostly been used for filtering signals or images (in combination with [signal-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing), [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) or [computer-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision)). To me these are different meanings, the first one selects a subset of data, the other transforms the data.

I don't know if there's a good way to disambiguate these two different meanings. I see two solutions:

1. Rename [filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filtering) to [signal-filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signal-filtering) or similar, this would require work to look through the 7,746 posts with this tag and ensure the new tag applies or if [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter) was intended.

   At the same time we could rename [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter) to [data-filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-filtering) or similar, so that no ambiguous tag names remain.
2. Embrace the ambiguity and hope that other tags do the job of disambiguating. We accept the synonym and move on.

Comment: OK, since I posted this, two people (net) have downvoted the synonym proposal. **Please hold on with voting there**, let's discuss this first!

Comment: I've also had to remove the `filter` tag many times from questions about signal filtering. It's great that you bring this forward. I prefer proposal 1: no ambiguous tag names (although I see the problem that in the future someone will re-create a `filter` tag with either meaning). If `filtering` is renamed to `signal-filtering`, the "Use this tag for questions asking for help with filtering datasets" part should probably be deleted from its description